# How to return a value after a index is out of range

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to do a [LeetCode Two Sum](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/), and I'm having issues with it. I have a for loop that updates the index call after each failed attempt, but when I get too high, it won't return a value if it is out of range, but instead will just throw an index out of range error.

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        numneeded = target - nums[0]
        for number in nums:
            x = 1
            while x <= len(nums):
                y = 0
                if nums[y] == target / 2:
                     y += 1
             
                if nums[x] == -1:
                    return(y, x)
                    
                if nums[x] == numneeded:
                    return (0, x)
                else: x += 1
            return(y, x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This'll simply pass for twoSum:

```
class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums, target):
        indices = {}
        for index, num in enumerate(nums):
            if target - num in indices:
                return indices[target - num], index
            indices[num] = index
```

For your question, in python 3, we would use `//` instead of `/` which we would usually use for python 2:

```
from typing import List


class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
        numneeded = target - nums[0]
        for number in nums:
            x = 1
            while x <= len(nums):
                y = 0
                if nums[y] == target // 2:
                    y += 1

                if nums[x] == -1:
                    return(y, x)

                if nums[x] == numneeded:
                    return (0, x)
                else:
                    x += 1
            return(y, x)


print(Solution().twoSum(nums=[2, 7, 11, 15], target=9))
```

---

### References

- For additional details, you can see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/two-sum/). There are plenty of accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) and explanations, efficient algorithms, as well as asymptotic [time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) complexity analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup> in there.

Comment: ok, I'm still new to this, so what exactly does enumerate do? and wouldn't returning the indices return the actual number, not the position?